# Sending survey via teams channel in Bot Framework after Push notifications

Tags: c#, push-notification, botframework, microsoft-teams, .net-4.8

I am working on a Bot Project.So, we have enabled push notification.
So, we now also want to add Survey along with the Push notification message. Please let me know, the possible ways.

Comment: Can you please go into greater detail regarding what you're hoping to achieve? What Teams client are you targeting? Do you want the push notification popup, itself, to contain the survey?

Comment: @mdrichardson : Yes, I want Push notification popup, should also contain survey

Comment: I don't *believe* it's possible to include a survey in the push notification, but I've added the `microsoft-teams` tag so they can jump in and support. For the push notification, you can use [Proactive Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp), and here's [a good Teams Sample.](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot)